# Images load on localhost, but not loading when deployed to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Hi good folk of Stackoverflow. I have a problem that's doing my head in. I have a Js file that loads images into my web app. When I test it on localhost, it loads the images just fine. I also have a "ticking" noise that loads from it that works locally. My problem arises when I deploy everything to my production server. My images dont display and my ticking noise doesn't play. I am hoping  one of you can point me in the right direction as to why this is happening.

How my folder is setup

[image: 1]

Here is my .js file:

```js
// Super Wheel Script
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    
    
    
    
    $('.wheel-with-image').superWheel({
        slices: [
        {
            text: 'images/1.png',
            value: 1,
            message: "Transactional Lend Pillar",
            background: "#f3971c",
            
        },
        {
            text: 'images/2.png',
            value: 1,
            message: "Commercial Property Finance Lend Pillar",
            background: "#00a4aa",
            
        },
        {
            text: 'images/3.png',
            value: 1,
            message: "Agriculture Lend Pillar",
            background: "#f3971c",
            
        },
        {
            text: 'images/4.png',
            value: 1,
            message: "Structured Finance Solutions Lend Pillar",
            background: "#00a4aa",
            
        },
        {
            text: 'images/5.png',
            value: 1,
            message: "Commercial Property Finance Lend Pillar",
            background: "#f3971c",
            
        },
        {
            text: 'images/6.png',
            value: 1,
            message: "ABF & FML Lend Pillar",
            background: "#00a4aa",
            
        },
            
            {
            text: 'images/7.png',
            value: 1,
            message: "Transactional Lend Pillar",
            background: "#f3971c",
            
        },
        {
            text: 'images/8.png',
            value: 1,
            message: "Transactional Lend Pillar",
            background: "#00a4aa",
            
        },
        {
            text: 'images/9.png',
            value: 1,
            message: "Agriculture Lend Pillar",
            background: "#f3971c",
            
        },
        {
            text: 'images/10.png',
            value: 1,
            message: "Structured Finance Solutions Lend Pillar",
            background: "#00a4aa",
        }
],
    text : {
        type: 'image',
        color: '#CFD8DC',
        size: 25,
        offset : 10,
        orientation: 'h'
        
    },
    line: {
        width: 0,
        color: "#78909C"
    },
    outer: {
        width: 10,
        color: "#e6e6e6"
    },
    inner: {
        width: 10,
        color: "#78909C"
    },
    marker: {
        background: "#ff0000",
        animate: 1
    },
    width: 700, 
    selector: "value",
    
    });
        
    
    
    
    
    
    var tick = new Audio('media/tick.mp3');
    
    $(document).on('click','.wheel-with-image-spin-button',function(e){
        
        $('.wheel-with-image').superWheel('start','value',1);
        $(this).prop('disabled',true);
    });
    
    
    $('.wheel-with-image').superWheel('onStart',function(results){
        
        
        $('.wheel-with-image-spin-button').text('Spinning...');
        
    });
    $('.wheel-with-image').superWheel('onStep',function(results){
        
        if (typeof tick.currentTime !== 'undefined')
            tick.currentTime = 0;
        
        tick.play();
        
    });
    
    
    $('.wheel-with-image').superWheel('onComplete',function(results){
        //console.log(results.value);
        if(results.value === 1){
            
            swal({
                type: 'success',
                title: "A question about...", 
                html: results.message
            });
            
        }else{
            swal("Oops!", results.message, "error");
        }
        
        
        $('.wheel-with-image-spin-button:disabled').prop('disabled',false).text('Spin');
        
    });
    
    
    
    
    
});
```

Comment: Have you actually proved that the directory structure is the same on both servers? Also, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: See browser console/network for errors. Possibly CORS is the reason

Comment: Probably something wrong with asset paths. In the browser's dev tools, Network tab, look at what is requested and compare it to what should be requested.

Comment: You wont believe this sh!t, I wasn't putting the files into the root of the directory, I could kick myself. Thanks for your replies. Much apreciatted.